# Can I pickle a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle

Will I be able to pickle all the .meta, .data and checkpoint files of a tensorflow model? That's because I want to run a prediction on my model and if i deploy it , the files can't be on disk right? I know about the tensorflow  serving but I don't really understand it. I want to be able to load the tensforflow files without accessing the drive all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pickle is not recommended. Instead, they have created a new format called "SavedModel format" that serves this exact purpose.

See: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

Comment: My model isn't using keras. Its just tensorflow and it saves as those three files mentioned in the question. I have used the saver model to save it as these files. I want to access them remotely without accessing my drive repeatedly , so that's why I asked if pickle is possible.

Comment: What do mean by accessing the files repeatedly? When deploying you load the model into the RAM one time